# How to create a modal that opens when a function is called?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having issues attempting to create a modal that opens when a certain area of an image map is clicked.

Below is the code from my HTML file:

```
 <head link rel="stylesheet" href="ryanspagecss.css"></head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
    <script src="lotrpage.js"></script>
    <map name="lotrmap">
        <area shape="poly" href="" coords="405, 50, 463, 80, 461, 141, 408, 173, 354, 144, 353,81" onclick="playerSelect()">
    </map>

    <div id="selectModal" class="selectModal">
            <p>This is some text in the modal...</p>
    </div>
```

Below is my CSS:

```
    #selectModal {
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: pink;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 9999;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}
```

Below is my JavaScript:

```
    function playerSelect(){
      //Show Modal
      let selectModal = document.getElementById('selectModal');
      selectModal.style.display = "block";
  
  }
```

I understand that in order to change my Div from invisible to visible I need to change the display value to block from none - Which is what I've attempted to do with my JavaScript function.

When I select my image it does nothing. - What am I missing here?

Comment: The element `#selectModal` is missing from the example

Comment: Hi, I've updated my example. Thanks

Comment: I tried to make a [mcve] of your issue. https://jsfiddle.net/ The only thing I changed  that made a difference was adding `#` to the area href. Otherwise it would try to change the URL when I clicked it. It works after that...

Comment: @evolutionxbox Just attempted adding the # as well as removing the href altogether. Neither worked sadly.

Comment: can you see that my example worked? May you share a [mcve] of your issue where it does work?

Comment: Hey @evolutionxbox - Your links just take me to a help screen and a fresh window of jsfiddle.net? Apologies if i'm missing something.

Comment: no sorry the link I posted doesn’t work for some reason. I’ll try again.

Comment: Please check https://jsfiddle.net/vn2jka9f/. It works as expected?

Comment: Hey @evolutionxbox - I can see you've added the # to the href but it doesn't seem to have anywhere to click on the image to open a modal?

I'm beginning to think that web tools are a little out of scope for my desired objective..

Comment: There is a place to click the image. Use the tab key to find it. You placed the area on the right side of the image.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Couldn't figure out why your code was working and mine wasn't. I even copy and pasted my code into JSFiddle and it worked... then I found where my problem was.. - My style sheet wasn't linked correctly.

Instead of 
<head link rel="stylesheet" href="ryanspagecss.css"></head>

It should have been 

    <head> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ryanspagecss.css">
    </head>

It just didn't throw any syntax errors so didn't spot it.

Thanks so much for your help Evo. Using JSFiddle is something I'll be using moving forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After realising a commenter's code and some minimal code of mine worked in JSFiddle - tested to see if my CSS would change the colour of some random text.... it didn't.

It turned out that I had my CSS linked incorrectly. No syntax errors were returned so hadn't spotted it.

Instead of

```
<head link rel="stylesheet" href="ryanspagecss.css"></head>
```

It should have been

```
<head> <link rel="stylesheet" href="ryanspagecss.css"> </head>
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `document.getElementById('selectModal')`, the function will try to find an element in your html whose id equals `selectModal`. In this case, your modal has the id `selectOwner`.

You should try to change your code to `document.getElementById('selectOwner')`

If you want your function to find the modal using the class name, you would have to use document.getElementsByClassName('selectModal'). Just consider that this will return something like an array of divs that contain this class (it's actually a HTMLCollection, not an array)

Comment: Hey - just updated the example. Instead I've updated the ID name to "selectModal"

Answer (score 0):

You have no element with ID `selectModal`. Try adding `id="selectModal"` to your div.

Comment: Hey - thanks for taking a look. I've updated my example, I left the div out accidentally.

Using class="selectModal" is also acceptable, correct?

Comment: @Jeavo no. The div must have `id="selectModal"` to work with your CSS and JS

Comment: @evolutionxbox Of course! GetElementByID requires it? Updated example to reflect, but still no cigar... sadly

Comment: @Jeavo What exactly is the issue? Is it displaying and not going away upon clicking the area still? Is it never displaying? Are there errors?

Comment: @purple No errors - essentially, clicking my area does absolutely nothing. It's worth noting that the "<p>This is some text in the modal...</p>" is always at the bottom left of my map image, irrespective of whether I've clicked the area or not. No div though, just the paragraph

Comment: The div should have `style="display:none"` in it's tag if you want it start out hidden by default. This will also hide the `<p>This is some text in the modal...</p>` part.

Answer (score -1):

yes you are correct on understanding the difference between display: "none" and display: "block"

I tried to run your code in my local which doesn't display anything in screen.

There are two possible solutions here

1. Please try and use this **map** & **area** tags with an image that help you display something in html which lets you click. ([link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap))
2. You can try to add a simple

   tag that displays some text in your html with same on click function. Paste this below code in your html and when you click, it should let you open the modal.

   ```
    <div onclick="playerSelect()">
        <p>
            Hi, Please click me to see the modal
        </p>
    </div>
   ```

Comment: Hey @Ankit - I successfully had my code linked up with a url + even had a function working successfully within my HTML:  (Just change the onClick function call to hexOwner)

    <script>
        function hexOwner() {
        alert("Ryan owns this hex");
        }

As for your second option, I don't quite understand how that would work? Surely that means - to call the function that displays the Div, I would have to select the invisible div itself.

Thanks